# How general is the class equation?

Tags: group-theory, group-actions

I generally see the class equation stated for the action of a group on itself by conjugation as follows where $C(G)$ is the centralizer of $G$:

$$|G|=|C(G)|+\sum{sizes\ of\ nontrivial\ conjugacy\ classes}$$

...or...

$$|G|=|C(G)|+\sum [G:C_G(x)]$$

It seems pretty clear that the more general statement also true. That is, if $G$ acts on a set $S$:

$$|S|=|Fix_G(S)|+\sum{sizes\ of\ nontrivial\ orbits}$$

...or...

$$|S|=|Fix_G(S)|+\sum [G:Stab_G(x)]$$

Pardon the poor notation. In both cases, I am summing over non-trivial conjugacy classes, and $Fix_G(S)$ indicates the set of points in $S$ fixed by all $g\in G$.

First, I am asking if my overall statement is correct.

Second, if the overall statement is correct, I was wondering if there is a reason why the conjugacy class statement seems to get more prominence than the general statement. Is the general statement not very useful?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the orbits of a group action partition the space that the group is acting on.  If that space is finite, then its cardinality is the sum of the cardinalities of the orbits. Moreover, you can indeed apply the orbit-stabilizer theorem to re-write the equation the way that you have.

The class equation is just this observation applied to the action of G on itself by conjugation.  Partitioning a group into conjugacy classes is a *major* feature of group theory, so it's helpful to have a name like "the class equation" to quickly identify what you're talking about.

Comment: Coming back to this, I'm thinking that this statement is just wrong: $|S|=|Stab_G(S)|+\sum{sizes\ of\ nontrivial\ orbits}$ because $|Stab_G(S)|$ is not generally equal to the count of the trivial orbits - it just happens to be in the case of a group acting on itself by conjugation.

Comment: Well, what do you mean by $\operatorname{Stab}_G(S)$?  If it means the set of points of $S$ which are fixed by the $G$-action, then it's correct, because each such point constitutes one trivial orbit.  These are the points which are individually $G$-stable.  If you meant something else, it's probably wrong.  I'm not sure if there's any standardized, accepted notation for stabilizers, fixed points, etc.  I'd probably write it $\operatorname{Fix}_G(S)$ or something, myself, since I think $\operatorname{Stab}$ is usually used for stabilizer subgroups, but of course it could also mean "stable."

Comment: Oh, the preceding isn't quite true, because there *is* an established notation for the fixed points of $S$ under $G$: $S^G$.  I don't particularly like this notation, but it is used very widely.

Comment: When I wrote $Stab_G(S)$ I meant $g\in G$ that fixes every point in $S$ - the stabilizer subgroup. That was how I was taught to use the notation. And I only just now clued in on that being wrong. I'll edit my question to use your better notation. This also gives my more of the answer I was looking for, I think. The case a group acting on itself by conjugation is unusual in that the set of fixed points and the stabilizer group are the same. And much of the utility comes from that fact: for example the proof that every p-group has a non-trivial center.